# JFrame Icon in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, icons, jframe

I'm Building a Swing Application and I need to know how to set an Icon for my JFrames through Netbeans 7.0 if it is possible.
Thank you for your cooperation.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you: [YouTube: Change the Icon in Java Frame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_35iro4b7M). It's from 2009, so it's not the latest, but it is still likely applicable.

Note that JFrame has a method, `setIconImage` that will do this for you and is easy to use.

Comment: maaybe he built app in JSR296, +1